# UIPATH: Verificar inicio de sesión web

Tags: .net, web

Existe alguna manera de verificar si se inicio sesión en una web que no sea con la actividad "Element Exists"?

Answer (score 0):

Pues según lo que necesites para tu proceso.

A priori, tienes dos maneras:

1. Element exist (si no puede iniciar sesión, puede continuar)
2. On Element Appear (si no puede iniciar sesión, rompe)

Ambos, deberías enfocarlos a algún elemento en pantalla que indique que has iniciado sesión (Link a LogOut tal vez).
La diferencia es que con el Element exist, si no se puede validar el inicio de sesión te devolverá un false.
Y con el On Element Appear, si no encuentra el elemento te devolverá una excepción de aplicación, lo cual si no la manejas podría romper tu proceso.

P.D: Si terminas usando el On Element Appear, acuérdate de poner la propiedad "Repeat" a "False".

Saludos.